# AES_ctr128_encrypt аналог на Python

Tags: python, telegram, криптография, aes, обфускация

Я пытаюсь переписать эту часть кода **С++** на Python:

```
AES_set_encrypt_key(encKeyBytes, KEY_LENGTH * 8, &encryptKey)    
AES_ctr128_encrypt(source, source, length, &encryptKey, encIv, encryptCount, &encryptNum);
```

**На Python** cейчас у меня это выглядит так:

```
tgcrypto.ctr256_encrypt(source, encKeyBytes, encIv, bytes(1))
```

*AES_ctr128_encrypt - это старый метод библиотеки openssl, но все еще применяется в офф. клиентах Telegram.*

**Проблема:** результат в первом и втором примере - отличается. Я определенно что-то делают не так.

Ссылка на C++ библиотеку: https://github.com/tsusanka/telegram-deobfuscator

Буду благодарен за подсказки.